# Access child custom record type from parent custom record type

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I've created a custom record type called PALLET as parent and a custom record type COMPONENT as child lines because it is one to many relationship. In another words, one PALLET can have multiple COMPONENTS. I can access PALLET from suitescript as below

```
function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var record = context.newRecord;
    record.setValue('custrecord166', '8888'); 
}
```

However, I cannot access COMPONENT from PALLET using suitescrpt and it return -1

```
function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var record = context.newRecord;
    var lineCount = record1.getLineCount({sublistId:"recmachcustomrecord_pallet_component"});
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sublist id when referenced from a parent account is `recmach`+ the *field* id of the custom field on the child record with is tagged to the parent.

ie.

parent record = `customrecordparent123` (Named "My Parent Record")

child record = `customrecordchild123`

on your child record, you will have a custom field of type list/record of type "My Parent Record".

This field will have "record is parent" ticked. Say this field's id is `custrecordmylinkedparent`.

when you reference the child record as part of a sublist, it will be `sublistId:'recmachcustrecordmylinkedparent'`, referencing the child record field.

!! Remember, the recmach is not the parent record, but the linking field on the child record.